# Linker script: defining symbol size and type

Tags: symbols, elf, linker-scripts

I know I can define a symbol/label in my (GNU binutils `ld`) linker script simply by assigning an address to the symbol like so: `my_symbol = 0xdeadbeef;`  But, ***what if I wanted to give that symbol a size*** (like `0x02`) ***and a type*** (like `OBJECT` or `FUNC`) as it would show up in the symbol table (`.symtab`)?